# What is the name for the ES2015 feature of implicit object names?

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6, syntax

What is the correct term for the ability in ES2015 to implicitly assign the value of a variable to an object member of the same name?

```js
const foo = 1;
const bar = { foo };
```

Comment: Shorthand property names

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015

Comment: Oh great, want to make that an answer?

Comment: Heh, someone voted to close this as off-topic for being "About general computing hardware and software"? Can't think of a topic much more related to programming than asking about syntax features.

Comment: @SteveBennett That was me and I didn't mean to offend. Your question is about the name of a feature which isn't exactly a good fit for a StackOverflow question. I bundle these sorts of questions along with the _"why is <insert language / popular framework feature> implemented this way"_ ones though this is at least objective. Anyway, it's only one vote and you're more than welcome to answer your own question

Comment: @Phil In this case, voting to close as a duplicate of the canonical topic about this syntax would be the way to go :-)

Comment: @Bergi I see a big difference between _"what is this syntax"_ and _"what is this feature called"_ but yes, that other post answers both questions

Comment: Heh, that sounds like a poor bundling to me. Questions like this are useful because once you know what a feature is called, you can google it, you can read the documentation, etc. It also would have helped me find the dupe target ;)